# How to resolve the 'foreign key not compatible' error when using 'add migration Initial' in ASP.NET Core migration?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, migration

when I was working on the e-tickets project, I was trying to use "add migration Initial", but I'm encountering this error (The relationship from 'Movie.Cinema' to 'Cinema.Movies' with foreign key properties {'CinemaId' : int} cannot target the primary key {'Logo' : string} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of foreign key properties with compatible types for this relationship.) However, since all the properties such as CinemaId seemed the same based on the tutorial I watched, I'm not sure how to resolve it. Here are my codes:

```
namespace eTicekts.Data
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext>options):base(options) 
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Actor_Movie>().HasKey(am => new
            {
                am.ActorId,
                am.MovieId
            });
            modelBuilder.Entity<Actor_Movie>().HasOne(m=>m.movie).WithMany(am=>am.actor_Movies).HasForeignKey(am=>am.MovieId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Actor_Movie>().HasOne(m => m.actor).WithMany(am => am.actor_Movies).HasForeignKey(am => am.ActorId);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        }
        public DbSet<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Actor_Movie> Actor_Movies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Cinema> Cinmeas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Producer> producers{ get; set; }


    }
}

namespace eTicekts.Models
{
    public class Actor_Movie
    {
        public int MovieId { get; set; }
        public Movie movie { get; set; }
        public int ActorId { get; set; }
        public Actor actor { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace eTicekts.Models
{
    public class Actor
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ProfilePictureURL { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Bio { get; set; }

        //relationships
        public List<Actor_Movie> actor_Movies { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace eTicekts.Models
{
    public class Cinema
    {
        [Key]
        public string Logo { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; }

        public string Description { get; }
        //relationships

        public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }
}

{
    public class ErrorViewModel
    {
        public string? RequestId { get; set; }

        public bool ShowRequestId => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(RequestId);
    }
}

namespace eTicekts.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        [Key]
        public  int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public int ImageURL { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set;}
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set;}
        public MovieCategory MovieCategory { get; set; }

        //relationships

        public List<Actor_Movie> actor_Movies { get; set; }


        //cinema
        public int CinemaId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CinemaId")]
        public Cinema Cinema { get; set; }

        //Producer
        public int ProducerId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ProducerId")]
        public Producer Producer { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace eTicekts.Models
{
    public class Producer
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ProfilePictureURL { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Bio { get; set; }

        //relationships
        public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }

}
```

I couldn't resolve the error "The relationship from 'Movie.Cinema' to 'Cinema.Movies' with foreign key properties {'CinemaId' : int} cannot target the primary key {'Logo' : string} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of foreign key properties with compatible types for this relationship." and I'm reaching out for help to solve it.

Comment: The following line belongs above the CinemaId and needs to be move up one line : [ForeignKey("CinemaId")]

Comment: No, what he did is right. The ForeignKey attribute can be used in the two ways. [See this](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/foreignkey-attribute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `Id` in Cinema, the Cinema class should be like this.

```
    public class Cinema
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Logo { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; }

        public string Description { get; }
        //relationships

        public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

as you can see from the error Cinema table's Key is  "string Logo { get; set; }"
which is string , and you Referring from movies table "int CinemaId { get; set;}"
which is int , so you can Add column cinemaid to cinema Table and make it Key , or you can change cinemaid's datatype in Movies as string.